# Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in linea xx

Tags: php, mysql, base-de-datos, phpmyadmin, pdo

No permite realizar la conexión al momento de intentar enviar datos la base de datos
esta es la conexión

```
<?php
function conect(){
    $conexion = null;
    $nom_servidor = "localhost";
    $username = "root";
    $password = "";
    try{
```

aqui se realizan las conexiones

```
        //Realiza la conexion con la base de datos
        $conexion = new PDO("mysql:host=$nom_servidor;dbname=sistem_fares",$username, $password, array(
            PDO::ATTR_EMULATE_PREPARES => false,
            PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE => PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION
        ));
        return $conexion; //devuelve la conexion
    }catch(PDOException $e){
        echo $e->getMessage();
        return null;
    }
}
```

$conexion se utiliza en esta linea.
$conexion->query($sql);

```
try {
        //almacenar consulta en la variable $sql
        $sql = "INSERT INTO inventario (codigo, nom_producto, costo, porc_venta,
        precio_venta, fecha, imagen)
    VALUES ('$v_ccodigo','$v_nproducto','$v_costop','$v_porcentajev','$v_pventa',
    '$v_fecha_creacion', '$v_simagen')";
        $conexion->query($sql); //ejecutar la consulta
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); //mensaje de error
    }
    $conexion = null; //cerrar la conexion
}
```

Answer (score 0):

La variable `$conexion` esta fuera del `escope` donde realizas la consulta. Por esa razón te dice que es `null`.

prueba a hacer
`$conexion = conect();` antes del try/catch

```
$conexion = conect();
try {
        //almacenar consulta en la variable $sql
        $sql = "INSERT INTO inventario (codigo, nom_producto, costo, porc_venta,
        precio_venta, fecha, imagen)
    VALUES ('$v_ccodigo','$v_nproducto','$v_costop','$v_porcentajev','$v_pventa',
    '$v_fecha_creacion', '$v_simagen')";
        $conexion->query($sql); //ejecutar la consulta
    } catch (PDOException $e) {
        echo $e->getMessage(); //mensaje de error
    }
    $conexion = null; //cerrar la conexion
}
```

Comment: ya lo hago estimado y aun nada

Comment: Aún nada... vale, pero ¿qué error te da? Comentas que no permite realizar la conexión, pero ¿cuál es el mensaje de error que indica?

Comment: el formulario aparece, pero al momento de enviar el registro a base de datos muestra el siguiente mensaje:
SQLSTATE[HY000] [2054] The server requested authentication method unknown to the client
Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to a member function query() on null in C:\xampp\htdocs

Comment: el error indica que la variable `$conexion` es `null`. En algún punto en tu código se vuelve `null` o la función conect te esta devolviendo `null`